# why can't I pass the return twice?

Tags: python, function, variables, methods, return

I'm practicing python and I don't understand why I am getting this error. I tried searching it but I can't find put why.

I tried to put pass_two = two(x) but it didn't work. it kept saying it was undefined.

can any one correct and explain why? thanks

```
def one():
    x = 'blue'
    return x

def two(x):
    y = 'red'
    xy = x+y
    return xy

def three(z):

    w = 'black'
    print('all three passes ' + z+w)

def main():
    pass_one = one()
    two(pass_one)

    pass_two = two()
    three(pass_two)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You dont pass an argument `pass_two = two()`. I think you wanted `pass_two = two(pass_one)`

Comment: `two` need an argument and you are not passing one at `pass_two = two()`

Comment: Function requires argument

Comment: I wanted to pass what I return from def one() to def two(), and pass what I get from def two() to def three()

Comment: I tried to put x for the argument but it said it was undefined

Comment: actually you were right about the pass_two = two(pass_one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the function `two` to work with an argument so if you try to type `two()`, Python will output `TypeError: two() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`.

Now, if you try to type `two(x)`without having defined `x` before, you will get a `NameError`.

Maybe you wanted to write `pass_two = two(pass_one)`